# load base template passed on parameter

Tags: django, dynamic, templates

I have a site where different projects/programs are listed, the list is dynamic so once a user clicks on a specific program e.g. /program/health the template should load one that has a "health" specific header (mast head). How can I load a base template based on the program selected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a combination of CSS class names from a template variable and include template tags to accomplish this?

Something like:

```
<body class="{{ program }}">
    <div>{% include program_specific_template %}</div>
    <div>Common stuff...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: how would you pass the template variable to the base template?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass the path to a template to a function, you may substitute the hard-coded string for some variable of your choosing. If you do this it is **extremele important** to make sure it is a sensible value. To be fair, the template system will escape dangerous stuff and will not go outside the specified template dir, but trying to load a non-existing template will cause the view to crash and you don't want that.

If you have a model for the program, then get the model and use the slug as a template name, like this:

```
p = get_object_or_404(Program, slug = slug_from_url_or_whatever)
template = "program_%s.html" % p.slug
```

It is also possible to pass a list of templates to the loaders. If it doesn't find the first one, it will try the next one, etc. For example:

```
render_to_response([template, "default_program_template.html"], ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use a [custom Context Processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) and some CSS to get the job done.

**settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"yourproject.context_processors.header_context")
```

**context_processors.py**:

```
def header_context(request):
    values = {'body_class': "default",}
    if request.path == "/program/health/":
        ## Don't really use an if block, it's just nasty.
        values['body_class'] = "health"
    return values
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
def view(request):
    ## Do magic stuff!
    return render_to_response("template.html",
               {},                         
               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template.html**:

```
<body class="{{ body_class }}">
    <!-- Whatever -->
</body>
```